# Insert / Update Records in MS SQL 2008 based on a second table, then keep dates consistent

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, insert

Sorry if this or something similar has been asked before but I've been searching for a while and can't find any answers or leads.

So I have two tables with data that looks like this:

TableA

```
PK  START    STOP       DATA
1  1/1/2013  12/31/2013  AAA
1  1/1/2014  12/31/2014  AAA
2  1/1/2013  12/31/2013  BBB
2  1/1/2014  12/31/2014  BBB
```

TableB

```
PK  DATE     DATA
1  5/1/2013  CCC
1  8/1/2014  (null)
2  6/1/2014  QQQ
```

Now what I need to do is update tableA to insert a copy of the preceeding record if there is a corresponding record in tableB between START and STOP.

For instance, in this example this would be my desired update to tableA:

```
PK  START    STOP        DATA
1  1/1/2013  4/30/2013   AAA
1  5/1/2013  12/31/2013  CCC
1  1/1/2014  7/30/2014   AAA
1  8/1/2014  12/31/2014  (null)
2  1/1/2013  12/31/2013  BBB
2  1/1/2014  5/31/2014   BBB
2  6/1/2014  12/31/2014   QQQ
```

This is what I've written so far but it doesn't seem to be working as the update to the previous record's date always gets messed up.

```
--For copying records
SELECT 
    A.PK, B.DATE AS START, A.STOP, B.DATA
INTO TEMP_TABLE
FROM TABLEA A
INNER JOIN TABLEB B ON B.PK=A.PK AND B.DATE BETWEEN A.START AND A.STOP

--For updating records
UPDATE A
SET A.STOP=DATEADD(DD,-1,TT.START)
FROM TABLEA A
INNER JOIN TEMP_TABLE TT ON TT.PK=A.PK AND TT.STOP=A.STOP

--Insert the records
INSERT INTO TABLEA SELECT * FROM TEMP_TABLE
```

Is there something wrong with my reasoning here or is there a better way to go about this? Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are there any restrictions regarding the number of rows in table B and the time periods in table A? Such as: table B will contain at most one row for each row in table A?

Comment: No restrictions on table B, the simplified version here is the result of several other scripts to clean up the data but there could be any number of records per PK in theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two suggestions. First, I think in your "copying records" select, your last selected column should be `B.DATA` rather than `A.DATA`.

Second, you name your temp table as `#TEMP_TABLE`. Using the hash prefix makes this an actual temp table, which will be created in `tempdb` and will pass out of scope when the session ends and won't be visible to other sessions.

With those two tweaks, your code appears to work with the simple example here. But if your actual data has more complicated relationships, such as tableb containing more than one row that corresponds to a given row in tablea, your approach may not hold up.

Comment: The A.DATA part was a shortsight in my pseudocode, the actual code contains B.DATA. Normally I would use #temp tables but in this case I want to go retain the data step-by-step hence the lack of the hash prefix. Table B is also not a 1-1 relationship, and is the result of much cleaning (but is accurate), so if there is problem with that approach please let me know if there is a better angle of attack.

Comment: If B could contain multiple rows that apply to a single A row, and your intent is to split the time period represented by A into contiguous (non-overlapping) periods, you probably need to use a cursor and process rows in B one at a time. That will kill your performance but will allow you to update the state of A as you go.